# Background with different colors, images and shape

Tags: html, css

I want background like this. How can I get this with pure CSS.

[image: Background Image]

I have searched for this but I didn't find any answer.

I want to ignore usages of large background images.

**UPDATE**

I have tried like this (only with color)

```
background : linear-gradient(125deg, #3081ff 31%, #3081FF 78%, #307aff 33%, #307aff 25%)
```

But, I want to add image with color.

Here is Fiddle which I have tried [Fiddle-Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/59s15zwz/1/)

And it have problem with responsive, you can check by resizing window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple background images:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, .5) 50%), url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-400-200-1.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or a pseudo-element:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-800-400-1.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, .5) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```